# Which mod adds this yew longbow?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, mod-identification

I found a bow in a cave and I don't know which mod adds the following attributes:

- It is a yew longbow (but looks like a normal bow, not like a longbow from trinkets, and yew is a tree from extra trees)
- It has a superior craftsmanship attribute.

I have installed some mods including extra bows, extra trees, forestry, trinkets contruct.

Can I craft a bow like this?

[image: what is that]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it's from a mod called "Minecraft Roguelike"

[Source](https://github.com/Greymerk/minecraft-roguelike/blob/master/src/main/java/greymerk/roguelike/treasure/loot/provider/ItemSpecialty.java#L243)